# trying to setup mysql on ubuntu for django but getting error 'django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1046, 'No database selected')'

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, ubuntu

**my Settings.py**

```
   DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'DATABASE' : 'DjangoProject',
            'USER' : 'myprojectuser',
            'PASSWORD' : 'Akbar@123456',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
            # 'default-character-se' : 'utf8',
           # 'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        }
    }
```

**SHOW DATABASES command on terminal**

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| DjangoProject      |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sample             |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**error**

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1046, 'No database selected')
```

I have granted the user rights on the database but it still showing error, please help i want to run mySql just like sqlite3 where you can see your databases in the admin panel, and works same once  settings are made, please tell if there is gui interface for mySQL and also how to see your database on the browser,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `NAME` in DATABASE dictionary

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'DATABASE' : 'DjangoProject',
        'USER' : 'myprojectuser',
        'PASSWORD' : 'Akbar@123456',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        # 'default-character-se' : 'utf8',
        'NAME': 'DjangoProject',
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it solved the error, can you please tell that is there any graphical interface for mysql and how to view it on browser

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked, for you question there is MySQL workbench